# Como faço uma classe java abstrata padrão DAO para herdar nas classes dao?

Tags: java, padrão-dao

Quero fazer uma Classe Abstrata em Java para utilizar nas classes Dao que irei utilizar em vários projetos, para não ficar repetindo o métodos de seleção, inserção, deleção e atualização em todas as classes dao.

Eu não queria utilizar hibernate e outros.

Grato

Comment: Você quer criar um Template pra reutilizar métodos de uma classe Abstrata para as operações CRUD - Create, Read, Update, Delete?

E ai não ter de ter esses métodos reescritos em suas classes DAO?
Você tá usando um banco relacional?
Qual o problema em ter que implementar esses métodos?
E qual o problema em usar JPA?

Comment: Dê uma olhada [neste](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/data_access_object_pattern.htm) tópico da Tutorial's point. ele explica bem o que você procura:

Comment: Uso Banco relacional, eu nao tenho problema, mas queria desenvolver uma propria pra metodos especificos pois nao utilizarei herança e sim tabelas relacionais. rs

Comment: Tiago, ainda nao ficou claro pra mim qual è seu proposito. Nao precisar escrever métodos com select, update?
Ou você quer aprender como Funciona o DAO?
Se você quer uma abstração da camada, me parece que você quer construir uma pequena API para abstrair as operações CRUD, mas você vai acabar tendo de mapear as entidades. Explique melhor o seu propósito.

Comment: é nao escrever os metodos DAO em todas as classes, para eu fazer o meu padrao de consultas

Comment: Há uns anos atrás, eu tinha um GenericDAO que era uma classe abstrata exatamente com essas características, e parecia ser uma boa ideia. No final das contas acabei abandonando isso, pois tinha uma forte tendência a criar mais problemas do que resolver.

Comment: Eh tipo essa GenericDAO msm Victor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente você gostaria de implementar um [CrudRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) que faz parte do Spring Data, mas é usado como uma estratégia para entidades persistentes (JPA).

Como você não deseja usar nenhum provider JPA, seguimos para uma alternativa:

O [Spring Data JDBC generic DAO implementation](https://github.com/nurkiewicz/spring-data-jdbc-repository) que busca uma abordagem generica, leve e simples para RDBMS, foi baseado no [JdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) (Spring Framework).

Ele entrega a implementação completa da abstração PagingAndSortingRepository do Spring, sem usar JPA, XML.

```
public interface PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends CrudRepository<T, ID> {
             T  save(T entity);
    Iterable<T> save(Iterable<? extends T> entities);
             T  findOne(ID id);
        boolean exists(ID id);
    Iterable<T> findAll();
           long count();
           void delete(ID id);
           void delete(T entity);
           void delete(Iterable<? extends T> entities);
           void deleteAll();
    Iterable<T> findAll(Sort sort);
        Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable);
    Iterable<T> findAll(Iterable<ID> ids);
}
```

Seguem uma referencia de utilização:

```
Page<User> page = userRepository.findAll(
    new PageRequest(
        5, 10, 
        new Sort(
            new Order(DESC, "reputation"), 
            new Order(ASC, "user_name")
        )
    )
);
```

E [uma ótima materia](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/spring-data-jdbc-generic-dao) com idealizador da api *Tomasz Nurkiewicz*.